# Excel 2010 Macro - Creating txt files with names from ColA and content ColB. Stacko. solutions not work

Tags: excel, vba

I have found some answers/examples here on stackoverflow for an issue where in Microsoft Excell 2010, I want to create a txt files for each cell from for e.g. ColumnA which would contain file names, and ColumnB which would contain what is inside certain text file, however one example doesn't work at all, and second bugs after few files created.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CreateTextFile method which will create your file and provide a TextStream object which you can use to write to the text files. [Microsoft Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa265018(v=vs.60).aspx)

Here's a code example that will do what you asked.

```
Sub CreateTxt()
Dim my_range As Range
Dim pth As String

Set my_range = Selection

For Each x In my_range.Rows:

    pth = "C:\excel_test\" + x.Cells(1) + ".txt" 'file name in column A

    Set file_sys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set txt_file = file_sys.CreateTextFile(pth, True)
    txt_file.WriteLine (x.Cells(2)) 'content in Column B
    txt_file.Close

Next x

End Sub
```

Just remember, in order to create a file you need adequate permissions on the path you're writing to - I had to run excel as administrator to get the functionality.

Also, the True value in the CreateTextFile method is necessary to overwrite any files with the existing file name, if set to false it will throw an error when trying to write to the file.